# IE10 responsive bug with media queries

Tags: internet-explorer, css, internet-explorer-10

I'd used the viewport hack but it's still not perfect.

like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
  @-ms-viewport{
      width: device-width;
  }
}
```

but it doesn't seem to scale from `0px` to `480px`, my class applied when it's around `480px`. Is this a bug?

Comment: @codehorse you're right, maybe perfection is not possible

Comment: @codehorse isn't IE the default browser (and probably the only one) in Windows Phones?

Answer (score 0):

I would have to assume that this is a bug.  As said by codehorse anything with a screen size that small will probably not be using IE10 unless it happens to be a windows phone.

If you are using a fluid layout for your site I would recommend using width: 100%; this might fix your problem, doubtful but sometimes little things like this work wonders.  To be honest if your site isn't that big yet, I would focus more on other things as most people aren't going to be viewing it that small on IE10 like has been said.